# Finding the closest values in a multi-indexed dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm trying to select data based on closest values in the indices of a pandas dataframe.
I read the file from excel and multiindexed the dataframe like this:

```
df = df.set_index(['Year', 'delta', 'ix'])
```

The result looks a little something like this.

```
Year    delta       ix          Temp
2010    6           4           34
                    5.1         38
        7           4.5         36
                    3.7         37
2011    6           4           37
                    5.1         35
        7           4.5         38
                    3.7         41
2012    6           4           43
                    5.1         39
        7           4.5         38
                    3.7         37.5
```

The values I want to search for are not present in this dataframe so I want to look for the next closest values. For instance I want to find Temp value for delta of 6.7 and ix of 4.9 in year 2011, but since these values are not in the dataframe, I should get the Temp value with the closest indices, which in this case are delta of 7 and ix of 5.1.
So, the row I take the data from is,

```
Year    delta       ix          Temp
2010    7           5.1           39
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The definition of closest values is unclear - should you take the row with the column that is closest to its target, the row where the average distance is the smallest or another way? For instance, if one row has the exact requested delta but is very far in ix, and the other is pretty close on all of them, which would you want chosen?

Comment: Sorry I should have elaborated a bit more, now that I think.

If there is a case where we have an exact match for delta, but ix is far away compared to a case where both delta and ix are close but not exactly equal to the query, then it would be preferable to choose the case where both values are close to the query, rather than the one where one is an exact match but other is nowhere near the value queried.

Comment: @HamzaWaheed that's a start but you still haven't defined what close means.  A formula (e.g. dist = np.abs(ix- ix0) + np.abs(delta -delta0)) would remove all ambiguity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reset the index to work on columns which would be easier.

Then you can sum the distances of the columns from their targets and use the [idxmin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html) function to get the closest row id:

```
df = df.reset_index()
closest_row_id = ((df["Year"] - wanted_year).abs() + (df["delta"] - wanted_delta).abs() + (df["ix"] - wanted_ix).abs()).idxmin()
closest_temperature_row = df.loc[closest_row_id]
# If you only want the temperature you can do:
# closest_temp = df.loc[closest_row_id, "Temp"]
df = df.set_index(['Year', 'delta', 'ix'])
```